# laravel 4 eloquent inserting column without asking

Tags: laravel-4, facebook-php-sdk, eloquent

I'm implementing social login in a Laravel 4 site, I started with Facebook using the official facebook-php-sdk and all works well. Except for when a user logs in for the first time. When this happens I want to create a account in our database using the eloquent "User" model.

Some how the columns "code" and "state" get added by eloquent and I can't figure out why, any explanation would be appreciated.

I did notice in the the Laravel error screen that there is a value QUERY_STRING which contains these two values, yet I can't figure out how they get in my query.

The code that gets executed:

```
class SMLogin extends BaseController {

private $credentials = null;

loginWithFacebook () {

//set social medium
$medium = 'facebook';
$this->credentials = Config::get($medium.'.credentials');

$params = [
   'redirect_uri' => route('login.fb'),
   'scope' => Config::get('facebook.scope'),
];
//get a FB object
$facebook = new Facebook($this->credentials);

//if there is a code available
if (Input::has('code')) {

    //get the user ID
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();

    //if the code is 0 send user to Facebook
    if ($uid == 0) {
...
    //if new user create the user local
    } else {
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');

        //get user of create it
        $user = User::firstOrNew([
            'email' => $me['email'],
        ]);

        $user['password'] = 'test';

        if (!$user->verified) {
            $user->verified = var_export($me['verified'],true);
        }

        if (isset($user->gender)) {
            $user->gender = ($me['gender'] == 'female')? 'F' : 'M';
        }

        if (isset($user->first_name)) {
            $user->first_name = $me['first_name'];
        }

        if (isset($user->last_name)) {
            $user->last_name = $me['last_name'];
        }

        //save user
        $user->save();
```

my User model:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class User extends Ardent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    use SoftDeletingTrait;
    public $autoHydrateEntityFromInput = true;
    public $forceEntityHydrationFromInput = true;
    public static $passwordAttributes = ['password'];
    public $autoHashPasswordAttributes = true;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $guarded = [
        'id',
        'password',
        'twinfield_customer_id',
        'deleted_at',
        'updated_at',
        'created_at',
        'name',
        'business_name',
        'password_confirmation',
        'terms',
        'business_id'
    ];
    protected $hidden = ['password'];
    public static $rules = [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'birthday' => 'sometimes|date',
        'gender' => 'in:M,F',
        'password' => 'required'
    ];
    public static $relationsData = [
        'business' => [self::BELONGS_TO, 'Business'],
        'orders' => [self::HAS_MANY, 'Order'],
        'social_media'  => [self::HAS_MANY, 'SocialUser']
    ];
    public function businesses(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Business')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('admin','invited_by');
    }
    public function getAdminBusinesses($called_direct = true){
        $res = $this->businesses();
        if($called_direct)
            return $res->get();
        else
            return $res;
    }
    public function getFinishedAdminBusinesses(){
        return $this->getAdminBusinesses(false)->where('finished','=', true)->get();
    }
    public function getUnfinishedAdminBusinesses(){
        return $this->getAdminBusinesses(false)->where('finished','=', false)->get();
    }
    public function getAuthIdentifier(){
        return $this->getKey();
    }
    public function getAuthPassword(){
        return $this->password;
    }
    public function getReminderEmail(){
        return $this->email;
    }
    public function getRememberToken(){
        return $this->remember_token;
    }
    public function setRememberToken($value){
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }
    public function getRememberTokenName(){
        return 'remember_token';
    }
    public function displayName(){
        if(!empty($this->prefix))
            return $this->first_name.' '.$this->prefix.' '.$this->last_name;
        else
            return $this->first_name.' '.$this->last_name;
    }
    public function getType(){
        if($this->business_id){
            return 'consumer';
        }else{
            return 'client';
        }
    }
    public function isType($type){
        return $this->getType() == $type;
    }
    public function setEmailAttribute($value){
        $this->attributes['email'] = strtolower($value);
    }
}
```

this generates the following error:

```
Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S22) 
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'code' in 'field list' 
(SQL: insert into `users` (`email`, `password`, `verified`, `code`, `state`,
`updated_at`,  `created_at`) values (rrr+fb@gmail.com, 
$FNbwC4DDHb36gekSN5GstOkVxg7tynrn2Dm/AcsQo2V3DRuboj/P6, true, 
AQCEHr04ZAPiY4CiZ1O8H6_-fofXqQkL48uvK-VO5Hm5tENQwGdm6inB3q5OZu-kniLuegDo-CMgwWvP7n3cfzNODfX_TqrIf6nfgFMdbl6HI4JGxs_nsOwKlW0cZAlfNFXFrnCTZpDOwm5bsHILN0mRiVNUZ5DrETnhXRQUa8icWL19RDpQ8RHzWlC-dNS4Puc3SRglsXYOx6PlegioAf31WGJ_C-kTQMKT9drFyQ8ewhhkDtycuFFWIk-bH0lXQr0wIL-iU2HKK8jy6XNQ7Lw9oWD0BBdkLsGqDiqsQmaVNyBXprFqn_buz2KyoNPMWw2lyAF9TJJ_YSbODVtMN5fV, 33faff5edfdad403d8650ba7a057e055, 2014-08-19 21:17:52, 2014-08-19 21:17:52))
```

Comment: Maybe it's an event listener in your user model? (post it?) Or perhaps it's a package trying to be too clever or incorrectly configured? (give us a list of any non-default service providers from `app/config/app.php`?)

Comment: Thx for the pointer! Didn't think about looking in my model, stupid. The $autoHydrateEntityFromInput is the cause I am guessing. If you post your input as an anwser I can give you points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your model for listeners / observers (i.e. `Users::saving(...)`). This are usually declared inside a `boot` method. Or, for added sneakiness, as was apparently your case, check for traits, then see if the traits themselves are adding listeners.